# MySQL Json function, output string instead json object

Tags: mysql, json, function

I have function

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION sf_textjson()
RETURNs json
BEGIN
declare s JSON;
SET s = JSON_OBJECT('year', 2024);
RETURN JSON_OBJECT('obj', s);
END
```

And result of select _sf_textjson() is

{"obj": "{"year": 2024}"}

What I need to do, to having next result:

{"obj": {"year": 2024}}

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION sf_textjson()
RETURNs json
BEGIN
declare s JSON;
RETURN JSON_OBJECT('obj', JSON_OBJECT('year', 2024));
END
```

Gives correct result, but I need compute some variables

Comment: O_O MySQL does not support `OR REPLACE` in `CREATE FUNCTION`..

Answer (score 0):

I tested your functions in MySQL 8.2. They both work as you intend, creating a JSON object with a nested JSON object.

So you must be using MariaDB, not MySQL. I tested the function in MariaDB 11.2, and I can reproduce the unwanted behavior you describe, the JSON variable is converted to a string.

Please be aware that MariaDB and MySQL are effectively different products. In particular, they both implemented JSON features after MariaDB forked, so they behave differently. MySQL implemented a full-blown data type for JSON, but MariaDB basically implemented it as little more than an alias for the `TEXT` type with a few extra functions.

I was going to suggest using `JSON_OBJECT('obj', CAST(s AS JSON))` which is a way to convert a string to JSON if the string contains value JSON syntax. That works in MySQL.

But MariaDB doesn't implement `CAST(... AS JSON)`.

I found this workaround:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sf_textjson()
RETURNs json
BEGIN
declare s JSON;
SET s = JSON_OBJECT('year', 2024);
RETURN JSON_OBJECT('obj', JSON_EXTRACT(s, '$'));
END
```

I tested this on MariaDB 11.2, and it works as you intend:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+---------------------------------------+
| VERSION()                             |
+---------------------------------------+
| 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 |
+---------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT JSON_PRETTY( sf_textjson() ) AS _result;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| _result                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| {
    "obj": 
    {
        "year": 2024
    }
} |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

MariaDB is not MySQL. We should all stop thinking of it as a  "drop-in replacement for MySQL," no matter what their marketing claims. It already has numerous features that are incompatible, and this list is growing larger over time.